# Excel VBA ActiveWindow.Visible hiding the wrong workbook

Tags: excel, vba, visible, active-window

I want to open a workbook (WB1) and then as it's opened, another workbook (WB2) is opened.  I want WB2 hidden.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\WB2.xlsm"
ActiveWindow.Visible = False

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far and what it does is hide BOTH workbooks.  I want WB1 to remain on top and visible.

Thank you!  Josh

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wb as workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    set wb=Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\WB2.xlsm")
    wb.Windows(1).Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, please explain the code, not just throw it around.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - you are quite free to post your own "better" answer if you feel all answers should include an explanation.

Comment: I do not understand why it is so difficult to put a small text around like any other people doing it, but I will definitely upvote an answer with such a text around.

Comment: It has nothing to do with upvote. It is about how the site is supposed to work. That is the reason why I will prefer an alternative answer with an upvote if someone publishes one. Surely, throwing random code around is not as educative as a clear explanation, even from a high rep user.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not "throwing random code around", but whatever. We're not debating this.

Answer (score 3):

an important part would seem to be how to turn view back on again.
other post is the answer..  i just had to see it work before i commited it.
hope this is enough to explain it,  may have been done in less space. thanks.

i would have to agree to post a couple words describing the key working line.  i am just novice at vb & have to say that 99% of posts require some research to get a needed variable in there.  i believe so enough to add some expletives as hours by many can be spent, trying to find the dang answer, but will refrain : ).

the consequence is:  everyone on the planet has to spend 2 to infinite hours.
(thanks for having code, to put code in a box, needs some tweaking for lines to include / space lines interfere?).

what i found:  changing out may not work:  .Visible  and  .Hidden
 - have no idea what the 1 in windows(1)  is for.

```
sub TEST1()    'in a module
'if want to happen when you open a wb, place in: "ThisWorkbook" module as:
'Private Sub Workbook_Open()    


    Dim wb As Workbook
    'Set wb = Workbooks("WB2.xlsm")      'YES
    'Set wb = Workbooks(Filename:="C:\WB2.xlsm")    'untried should work for path eg
    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\WB2.xlsm")   'original, with a command added: open
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If 0 = 0 Then   'set to: if 0 = 1 to skip test
      If wb.WINDOWS(1).Visible = False Then   'TOGGLES: press F5 or run macro button
        wb.WINDOWS(1).Visible = True
        MsgBox "Workbook is NOT Hidden" & Space(10), vbQuestion  'a good test method
      Else
        wb.WINDOWS(1).Visible = False     '<< line to use, to hide wb on open
        MsgBox "Workbook is Hidden" & Space(10), vbQuestion  'a good test method
      End If

    Else
        wb.WINDOWS(1).Visible = False     '<< line to use, to hide wb on open
    end if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old post but I thought I'd add in my version of the answer,as I was working on something similar.

```
Set m_WB = Workbooks("WB2FilePath\WB2.xlsm")
Windows(m_WB.Name).Visible = False
'Do work
'Set WorkBook to visible
Windows(m_WB.Name).Visible = True
```

Keep in mind, it would be good practice to set WB2 to visible once completed. This would avoid any memory being eaten up in the background without you knowing!

Cheers.