# Hide only the sheet related to showed user form

Tags: excel, vba

I use this code to hide the Excel sheet while I use the user form

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
Calculator.Show
End Sub
```

But it hides all the Excel sheets I'm working on. Is there another code that enables me to hide only the user form sheet?

Comment: There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538320/excel-vba-activewindow-visible-hiding-the-wrong-workbook)  post if you mean the workbook rather than the sheet or application?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Application.Visible = False` is referring to the entire Excel application, rather than a particular sheet or user form.

It's not entirely clear if you are trying to hide a sheet or a user form.
I think you are trying to hide a sheet and then show a user form.
If so, you can try this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Visible = xlSheetHidden
Calculator.Show
```

Note: you must hide the sheet before showing the userform (otherwise, the sheet will stay visible until the userform is closed).